# Can we have Macros inside a structure?

Tags: c

This code is taken from [Accessing SPI Devices in Linux](http://www.emcraft.com/stm32f429discovery/accessing-spi-devices-in-linux)

```
static struct spi_board_info
spi_stm32_flash_info__dongle = {
#if defined(CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV)
.modalias = "spidev",
#endif
.max_speed_hz = 25000000,
.bus_num = 3,
.chip_select = 0,
.controller_data = &spi_stm32_flash_slv__dongle,
};
```

spi_stm32_flash_info__dongle is atructure?

What is hapenning here? Do we have if else insde structure? Is there any significance of '.; before the variables? I know '.' is used for accesing structure elements, but here there is nothing before '.'

Answer (score 2):

1. Macros are a way to edit the text before compilation, and are processed before the compiler parses the code and figures out stuff like structs. In this case, the `modalias` line will either be there, or not, when the code is compiled.
2. The `.` in this case is used to initialize fields by their names. It's special syntax for this purpose.

Comment: I did  not get your second point. Whgat do you mean by 'initializing fields by ther name'. For example '.chip_select = 0' is not initlization by name.

Comment: Yes it is. The member named `chip_select` is being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `{}` are initializing the properties of the struct.

The `#ifdef` block is entirely legal within the struct, since the compiler will never see it; the preprocessor will either leave the contents of the block in or remove it, depending on the status of `CONFIG_SPI_SPIDEV`. The Windows API does a similar thing with some structs, adding or removing some members using `#ifdef` blocks.